# I am suffering from owin startup issue my Asp.net MVC5 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.

> The OwinStartup attribute discovered in assembly 'Search4Expert.Service.WebService' referencing startup type 'Search4Expert.Service.WebService.Startup' conflicts with the attribute in assembly 'Search4Expert.Web.UI' referencing startup type 'Search4Expert.Web.UI.Startup' because they have the same FriendlyName ''. Remove or rename one of the attributes, or reference the desired type directly.
>       To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
>       To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

[image]

Please any one help me.

Comment: Read and follow the instructions in the error message. It is clear as to what you need to do. It even tells you where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get this problem quite often in new ASP.NET applications.All you have to do is open you Web.config file and the following line to it under the `<appSettings>` element:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: That removes the error message, but my web page still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete project bin and obj folder files.
2. Rebuild the project.